# Entity Framework Core 6 - IEntityTypeConfiguration Separate Configuration Class

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Using EF Core 6, a sequence can be set up in the model builder, and then use to generate values for properties following way.

```
//DBContex Class
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("OrderNumbers");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .Property(o => o.OrderNo)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR shared.OrderNumbers");
}
```

I'm trying to move the DbConfigurations to a model-specific seperate configuration class:

```
//Seperate Configuration Class
public class OrdertEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
    {
        builder.HasSequence("OrderNumbers").StartsAt(1000);

    }
}
```

But it gives following error:

> Error CS1929  'EntityTypeBuilder' does not contain a definition
> for 'HasSequence' and the best extension method overload
> 'RelationalModelBuilderExtensions.HasSequence(ModelBuilder, string,
> string?)' requires a receiver of type 'ModelBuilder'

Any Solutions?

Comment: A sequence does not belong to an entity, you must keep in main DbContext

Comment: Yes, using the entity type configurations you still keep context (DB) level config like sequences in the OnModelCreating. :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/sequences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence does not belong to an entity, you must keep in main DbContext